# Multi-precision floating-point `scipy.misc.comb`

Tags: floating-point, combinations, factorial, multiprecision

I am using [`mpmath`](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) to write a binomial beta function fit to calculate extremely small probabilities.

Most of the functions I need are already included in mpmath or easy to rewrite. Sadly, however, `scipy.misc.comb` is not. I tried looking at the source code, but it seems to be [based on](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/special/basic.py#L1199) some `binom` function imported from [a file](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx) in which I cannot find its code.

How could I rewrite the scipy comb function (or write my own) without using for/while loops to calculate the factorials?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently `mpmath` does have a factorial function, with the deceptively intuitive name, `mpmath.factorial` -.-

So the solution to my query is simply:

```
def mp_comb(N,k):
    val= mpmath.factorial(N)/(mpmath.factorial(k)*mpmath.factorial(N-k))
    return val
```